# How to add jogl panel in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jogl

I am trying to write a java swing application that has buttons on one side and an openGL view (jogl)on the other side that displays things depending on what button is pressed. My problem is that when I split the JFrame into 2 sections, the first one takes the buttons fine, but I can't figure out how to add the OpenGL/jogl panel to the other side. I have a class that defines my jogl application, but how am I supposed to add it to a JFrame? I tried extending panel, GLJPanel, Frame (I didn't think that one would work to begin with), but have had no luck adding the jogl class to my frame. Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`GLJPanel` extends `JComponent` so it can be added to swing layouts. For example you can use a very simple [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) to show it next to some buttons.

```
Container pane = yourFrame.getContentPane();
JPanel panelWithButtons = new JPanel(); 

// add your buttons to panelWithButtons here

// add the panel with the buttons to the layout
pane.add(panelWithButtons , BorderLayout.LINE_START);

// create the jogl panel and add it to the layout
GLJPanel glPanel = ... 
pane.add(glPanel , BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) you can find more information on layout managers.