# Adding GLJPanel to Intellij IDEA as GUI Component

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jogl

I am attempting to get a split panel working with JOGL and Swing. Following the tutorials, I have created a `GLJPanel` that looks like the following:

```
public class GraphicsPanel extends GLJPanel {

public GraphicsPanel() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    final GLProfile glProfile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL4);
    GLCapabilities glCapabilities = new GLCapabilities(glProfile);
    this.addGLEventListener(new GLEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {

        }
    });
}}
```

I attempt to add this to the components, and the following error occurs:

[image]

From the tutorials and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704380/how-to-add-jogl-panel-in-java-swing) I was under the understanding that GLJPanel extended JComponent, and therefore I could add it. As a result of this error, the panel is never initialized in `$$$setupUI$$$` (the IntelliJ GUI autogenerated code) and so it never shows.

How can I get IDEA to recognize this component correctly so I can display a graphics panel in a split pane?

Comment: GLJPanel extends JPanel and JPanel extends JComponent: https://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/awt/GLJPanel.html The problem is in IntelliJ IDEA. JOGL is not to blame.

Comment: @gouessej Yeah that's what I figured. I have had nothing but problems with IDEA since starting this project.I was hoping I could use it because the IDE is very nice and convenient but it is looking like for GUI development I need to be on eclipse or netbeans :/.

Comment: I'm almost sure that this use case works in Netbeans.

Comment: It also works in eclipse. IDEA apparently uses their own thing. I even downloaded JFormDesigner and it seems incapable of handling GLJPanel. Interestingly hand programming the swing GUI, while annoying, is also a solution that works for IDEA.